# MSBUILD .NET v4 teamcity

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, teamcity

I have installed TeamCity Professional 8.1.3 (build 30101) onto a clean box and I am trying to run a new build. I have copied over the msbuild tools from my local dev machine to the new server and placed them in the x86 folder. I have also installed the IIS web role, .net feature, registered IIS from the cmd line, and installed MSBUILD tools 2013. For some reason, I still am unable to compile anything. I get the following error

> SGEN An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll.

Is anyone familiar with this error? I am trying to build an app in .NET v4 using msbuild tools v4.

Comment: You'll need to install .NET F/W (latest) on all the build agents - have you done this?  I've found manual configuration of MSBuild to be problematic in the past...

Comment: I currently only have one agent and it is on the local machine. I suppose I should just install VS2012 to see if that registers everything.

Comment: That will work, but TeamCity should run MSBuild with just the .NET framework. it's not very efficient rolling out VS to all your agents...

Comment: I think you are missing .NET SDK

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was installing VS2012 on my build machine. This may not be the most efficient, but it beats installing small packages and chasing around things that need to be registers in the GAC.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error building a project that targeted .NET Framework 4.5.1. I resolved the issue by installing [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Developer Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772)

You can get the SDK (aka Targeting Pack, aks Developer Pack) for other versions you may want to target at [.NET SDKs and Downloads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx)

Comment: I had had the same issue, but I've needed newer version of dev pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321